# How to scrape data from a web page derived from a form – using PuppeteerSharp, where the displayed page has the same url as the initial form page

Tags: screen-scraping, puppeteer-sharp

```
var options = new LaunchOptions
{
  Headless = false
};
var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();

var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options);
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

ViewPortOptions wp = new ViewPortOptions();
wp.Width = 900;
wp.Height = 950;

await page.SetViewportAsync(wp);
await page.GoToAsync(url);
```

- At this stage url displays a form. The user fills the form and presses Send.
- The following page shows the results of the form.
- The following statement bumps with an error "the execution context was destroyed, probably because of a navigation"

  var content = await page.GetContentAsync();
  var context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default);
  var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(content));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WaitForNavigation` to wait for the navigation triggered by a click action:

```
await Task.WhenAll(
    Page.WaitForNavigationAsync(),
    Page.ClickAsync("theSendButtonSelector")
);
```

Comment: My qusetion applies to debug where wait for completion does not apply.

Comment: What do you mean by debug?

Comment: I run it in debug mode and when the page is loaded i fill in data and submit the form. Then I wait at the next statement after the response with the full result. I can not acsess to the page containing the results.